# GetPosition in WxPython not returning the correct position

Tags: wxpython

I'm developing a user interface using WxPython, and I need to record two points manually selected on a StaticBitmap. This is in the function `on_left_click()` below.

```
import wx
import cv2
import numpy as np

class main_frame(wx.Frame):
    # Whether a new frame be displayed.
    _update_frame = True
    # A point on the image.
    _new_pt = wx.Point(0, 0)

    # The latest frame, used for shaft length measurement
    _current_frame = None
    # shaft shaft points.
    _shaft_pts = [wx.Point(0,0), wx.Point(0,0)]
    # shaft shaft point index
    _shaft_pts_idx = -1

    # Frame initialisation.
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(main_frame, self).__init__(parent,
                                         title=title,
                                         size=(800, 600),
                                         style= wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CAPTION | wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX )

        # create a panel to hold the image and buttons
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # Statusbar for displaying information.
        self.statusbar = self.CreateStatusBar()

        # Main horizontal sizer.
        hbox_main = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # create a static bitmap to display the webcam image
        self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, wx.ID_ANY, wx.NullBitmap)
        hbox_main.Add(self.bmp, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        # create the controls.
        self.shaft_box = wx.CheckBox(panel, label="Shaft detection")
        self.shaft_box.SetToolTip("Select two points to measure the shaft length. "
                                   "Left click to select point, "
                                   "middle click to delete last point")

        # Vertical sizer of buttons/displays.
        vbox_inputs = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox_inputs.Add(self.shaft_box, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)
        hbox_main.Add(vbox_inputs, 0, wx.EXPAND)

        # Add the horizontal sizer to the panel.
        panel.SetSizer(hbox_main)

        # Event bindings.
        # quit_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_quit_button_click)
        self.shaft_box.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.on_shaft_check)

        # Bitmap mouse click events.
        self.bmp.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_left_click)
        self.bmp.Bind(wx.EVT_MIDDLE_DOWN, self.on_middle_click)

        ########################################################################
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        # start a timer to update the image every x milliseconds.
        fps = 20
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.update_image)
        self.timer.Start(int(1000/fps)) # [ms]

        # show the frame.
        self.Show(True)

    # Left mouse click on the image.
    def on_left_click(self, event):
        # FIXME the position is off
        self._new_pt = event.GetPosition()

        if self.shaft_box.IsChecked():
            self.update_shaft(new_pt=True)

    # Middle mouse click on the image.
    def on_middle_click(self, event):
        if self.shaft_box.IsChecked():
            self.update_shaft(delete_pt=True)

    # "shaft Detection" clicked.
    def on_shaft_check(self, event):
        self._update_frame = not event.IsChecked()
        if event.IsChecked():
            self._shaft_pts_idx = 0
            self._current_frame = self.image.copy()
            self.update_shaft()
        else:
            self._shaft_pts_idx = -1
            self.statusbar.SetStatusText("")

    # Timer event, all processing to go in here and updates the image.
    def update_image(self, event):
        # Get frame.
        if (self._update_frame):

            _, frame = self.cap.read()
            self.image = np.uint8(frame)
            height, width = self.image.shape[:2]
            bitmap = wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(width, height, self.image)
            self.bmp.SetBitmap(bitmap)
            self.bmp.Update()

    # Select two points on the image which define the shaft.
    def update_shaft(self, new_pt=False, delete_pt=False):
        # Delete points.
        if delete_pt:
            if self._shaft_pts_idx > 0:
                self._shaft_pts_idx -= 1

        # Add new points.
        if (self._shaft_pts_idx >= 0) and (self._shaft_pts_idx < 2):
            # Add a new point.
            if new_pt:
                self._shaft_pts[self._shaft_pts_idx] = self._new_pt
                self._shaft_pts_idx += 1

            # Update the statusbar.
            if self._shaft_pts_idx == 0:
                self.statusbar.SetStatusText("Select two points on the image")
            elif self._shaft_pts_idx == 1:
                self.statusbar.SetStatusText(f"Point 1: {self._shaft_pts[0]}, "
                                             f" select another point")
            else:
                self.statusbar.SetStatusText(f"Point 1: {self._shaft_pts[0]}, "
                                             f"Point 2: {self._shaft_pts[1]}")

        # Draw points on image.
        img = self._current_frame.copy()
        height, width = img.shape[:2]
        for i in range(0, self._shaft_pts_idx):
            # img, loc, colour, marker type, size, thickness
            cv2.drawMarker(img,
                           (self._shaft_pts[i].x, self._shaft_pts[i].y),
                           (0,255,0),
                           cv2.MARKER_CROSS,
                           11,
                           2)
            cv2.putText(img,
                        f"Pt {i+1}",
                        (self._shaft_pts[i].x + 10,
                         self._shaft_pts[i].y),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.5,
                        (0,255,0),
                        2)
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(width, height, img)
        self.bmp.SetBitmap(bitmap)


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    frame = main_frame(None, title="Window")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The code worked fine initially, however I found that if I resized the window, the returned coordinates are wrong. After resizing, the origin appears to be the top left of the window, rather than the top left of the StaticBitmap. Any insights would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to calculate the relative positions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441144/in-wxpython-how-to-get-the-mouse-position-related-to-image-in-scrolledpanel

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. I did figure out what the problem is though - `hbox_main.Add(self.bmp, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)`. If I removed `ex.EXPAND` and set the proportion to 0 instead: `hbox_main.Add(self.bmp, 0, wx.ALL, 5)`, the coordinates are correct (as the image coordinate system's origin is at the top left).

Answer (score 0):

The issue, I believe, is that this line:

`hbox_main.Add(self.bmp, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)`

Centres the image in the StaticBitmap, which means the image coordinate system and the StaticBitmap coordinate system no longer matches if the window is resized. By changing the proportion to `0` and remove `wx.EXPAND`:

`hbox_main.Add(self.bmp, 0, wx.ALL, 5)`

I was able to overcome the issue.